# Windows 10 IoT RTSP Client

Tags: video, streaming, raspberry-pi2, iot

I just bought a Raspberry Pi2 and installed Windows IoT. I wanted to display a simple RTSP stream on a MediaElement but it seems that it's not supported. Anyone has a clue on how to make it work?

Comment: same problem here.... :/